# Is this a correct argument for an irred. polynomial of deg $m$ stays irred. over a field extension of deg $n$ if $n$ and $m$ are co-prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I have the following question:

> Let $F$ be a field and $K$ an extension field of $F$ of degree $n$. Let $f(x)\in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $m$. Suppose $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime. Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible as a polynomial in $K[x].$

Here is my solution:

Let $u$ be a root of $f(x)$ contained in some field extension of $K.$ 
From the hypothesis, we have $[K:F]=n$ and $[F(u):F]=m.$
Now, 
\begin{align}
[K(u):K][K:F]&= [K(u):F]\\
&=[K(u):F(u)][F(u):F],
\end{align}
which implies that $[F(u):F] \mid [K(u):K][K:F]$ i.e. $m \mid [K(u):K]n.$
Since $(m,n)=1,$ we have that $m \mid [K(u):K].$ Hence, $[K(u):K]\geq m.$

However, the degree of $u$ over $K$ is at most the degree of $u$ over $F,$ i.e.  $[K(u):K]\leq m.$

Hence, $[K(u):K]= m,$ and therefore $f(x)$ must be irreducible over $K.$

Is this correct and complete solution? If no, what is missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you not convinced yourself?

Comment: I am not sure about it, i.e. there might be some possible gaps

Comment: The best way to learn is to find out if there are no gaps! Look at each of your steps and find out why you were allowed to say what you said. It helps if you have your notes with you and quote the corresponding result at each step. You know, people answering your question do the same thing (except that they know the results per heart!).